# Why is the dismissible alert not showing up again after I click close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to use dismissible alert the same way as Bootstrap example shows:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

When the alert was shown, I clicked the close button. The alert was gone and everything was fine. But when I fired the same trigger trying to bring back the alert, it was not showing up again.

Is this the expected behaviour for dismissible alerts? How can I bring it back again? Thanks.

Comment: Have you bind this dynamically?

Comment: I used JQuery's hide() and show() on it.

Comment: But why you use hide because when you click close it already hide and if possible create fiddle for it.

Comment: I hide it in $(document).ready() so the alert wont be shown when the page is loaded.

Comment: You can do it using `$('#warningdiv').html('yourdata');` better to hide in ready

Comment: thanks for the suggestion...but still after I click close button the alert wont come back again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's .show() and .hide() methods instead, "data-dismiss" removes the alert element from html.

[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/4FaOZEGrGc)